# Help with resetting Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, apt, 16.04, 64-bit, reset

I installed Linux for the first time about 1 month ago. I love it. I'm running:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- HP Compaq 6200 Pro SFF PC
- Processor: Intel core i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz*4
- Graphics: Intel sandy bridge desktop
- Architecture: 64 bit

I have so many issues, I don't even know where to start:

1. I can't connect to WiFi, so I have to use ethernet.
2. Sometimes after a little while, my computer will freeze, but I can still hear that the computer is still running.
3. I've used `sudo apt-get install` for so many things at this point that I don't know which programs are necessary and which ones are not.

How can I reset everything?

When I install Ubuntu I get the message that parts are missings. One of them is iscsi.

I ran my computer in test drive and Ubuntu ISO: both Ubuntu server and ubuntu desktop AMD64.
First, I synced and then launched my computer, but when I started it up, my computer froze.
I can't install NVIDIA, kernel, or iscsi.

I am so sad. And I'm sorry for my English. I hope that someone can understand my issue and can help me out.
Please be nice to me. 
And no, I'm never going back to Windows.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a mess built up inside your disk made by mixing Server and Desktop. What I would to is to make a clean install of the Desktop edition (make sure to back up your documents, photos and files before performing it).

Comment: Thank you so mutch, for an answer. ❤ i try to clean  install of the Desktop edition and see if somthing get better. .

Comment: Gaah, I will take only Ubuntu base? For when i install i take Ubuntu desktop and server.

Comment: This question is very unclear and the title is just useless. You should ask one question about one issue at a time so accurate answers can be given and your title should allow people to get a basic understanding of the problem without reading the whole thing. Please split this in to multiple questions and give as much detail as possable on each one. Remember: We can't access your PC, all we have is what you tell us and if you don't give enough detail, we won't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Im Sorry. I get so stressed with this issus in computer. But thanx for answer Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly? I would save all your data and then set up (clean install) your PC with Ubuntu 16 again. Don't worry, the first time I used Ubuntu I had similar experiences.